# How do I use a variable in a new variable name?

Tags: php

I'm working with a while loop and I need to be able to assign the value of a variable to the name of a new variable. Here is the loop ($slide_number always returns a number):

```
$slide_number = theme_get_setting('slides_number');
$count = '1';

while ($count <= $slide_number) {
  $slide_path = theme_get_setting('slide_path_'.$count.'');
    if (file_uri_scheme($slide_path) == 'public') {
      $slide_path = file_uri_target($slide_path);
    }  
  $count++;  
}
```

So let's say $slide_number is 2. I need to produce $slide_path_1 and $slide_path_2, so how do I add the $count variable to $slide_path to create $slide_path_1 and $slide_path_2?

Comment: Why not use an array instead?

Comment: Maybe [variablevariables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) is the thing you are looking for?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered hundreds of times ... please try the search function before asking it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer with:

```
${'slide_path' . $count}
```

Answer (score 2):

While I don't recommand variable variables, this should do it:

```
$slide_path = "slide_path_" . $slide_count;
echo $$slide_path;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=1;
$var1='$slide_path_'.$count;
$$var1="here you go";
```

this will create a variable by name `$slide_path_1` and assign "here you go" to it

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused.  If you just need information from the previous run of the loop, have a variable at the end of the loop that holds that information.  Or load all of this into a declared array and then do what you want with it after you load it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is really bad practice...
Use an array to do this instead. Look into how arrays work, you can append all of your values together in a list with one and then you can view them however you need. Consider the following:

```
$slide_number = theme_get_setting('slides_number');
$count = '1';
$array_of_slides = array();

while ($count <= $slide_number) {
   $slide_path = theme_get_setting('slide_path_'.$count.'');
   if (file_uri_scheme($slide_path) == 'public') {

     $slide_path = file_uri_target($slide_path);

     // this line appends your value to the end of the array
     $array_of_slides[] = file_uri_target($slide_path);
   }  
   $count++;  
}

// this will print out the array so that you can see it
var_dump($array_of_slides);
```

Side note: the reason what you are trying to do is such bad practice is because if you had 4 billion variables declared as such your program will crash for sure and it might take your OS down with it.